Windows 11 installation takes 5x longer than Windows 10 - how to restore efficiency?
I'm looking for a way to make Windows 11's installation process more efficient, similar to how Windows 10 handled it.
Current pain points with Windows 11:
Let me voice my frustration about Windows 11's installation process taking significantly longer than Windows 10's, even on fresh installs.
In Windows 10, I could complete an installation in 10 minutes, set up the workstation as needed, and let updates run afterwards. It was efficient and respected an administrator's time. Even if Windows 10 tried to force premature updating, you could simply disconnect the network to complete the installation offline.
Windows 11, however, is far worse. It demands a working internet connection before it will even let you complete the installation! Then it forces massive updates BEFORE allowing any further setup. This completely wastes an administrator's time. In Windows 10, we could get our work done quickly and let the automated update process handle the rest in the background. In Windows 11, we're forced to wait endlessly before we can even begin our actual work!
This is a perfect example of Microsoft fixing what wasn't broken and making system administration needlessly time-consuming. The forced internet connectivity requirement is particularly egregious - it removes control from administrators who might need to complete setup before connecting to a network.
Is there a way to:

Skip the forced internet connection requirement during installation?
Defer updates until after basic system setup is complete?
Make the installation process more similar to Windows 10's workflow?

I'm specifically looking for legitimate workarounds or automation tools that could help streamline this process while maintaining system security and compliance.
